# How to show only time while input is dateTime

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I am making Class Schedule and display in a table where user will provide time input and in display schedule page it will show time upon selecting from drop down list.

my script:

```js
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#departmentId").change(function () {
            var departmentId = $("#departmentId").val();

            var json = { departmentId: departmentId };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("ViewAllScheduleByDept", "ClassSchedule")',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(json),
                success: function (data) {

                    $.each(data, function(i, row) {
                        $("table").append("<tr><td>" + data[i].Code + "</td><td>" + data[i].Name + "</td><td>R.No:" + data[i].RoomName + "," + data[i].DayName + "," + data[i].StartName + "-" + data[i].EndTime.ToShortTimeString() + "</td></tr>");
                        $(data).empty();
                    });


                }
            });
        });
    });

    </script>
```

my controller:

```js
public ActionResult ViewSchedule()
        {
            ViewBag.ShowDepartments = scheduleManager.GetAllDepartments();

            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult ViewAllScheduleByDept(int departmentId)
        {
            var schedules = GetAllSchedule();
            var scheduleList = schedules.Where(a => a.DepartmentId == departmentId).ToList();
            return Json(scheduleList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        private List<ViewSchedule> GetAllSchedule()
        {
            List<ViewSchedule> allViewSchedules = scheduleManager.ViewAllSchedule();
            return allViewSchedules;

        }
```

In Gate Way, i am converting time like this:

```html
 StartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["StartTime"].ToString()),
                    EndTime = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["EndTime"].ToString()),
```

Can't Find What I am Missing Here.Thanks In Advance For your Help.

Comment: Your question is little bit unclear but have you _ever_ try to use `TimeOfDay` property to get it?

Answer (score 0):

If i get you right, you want to display only the time of a DateTime. So instead of this:

```
 StartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["StartTime"].ToString()),
                EndTime = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["EndTime"].ToString()),
```

Try this:

```
 StartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["StartTime"]).ToShortTimeString(),
                EndTime = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["EndTime"]).ToShortTimeString(),
```

Comment: Tried That but then it says to set property as string. after doing so,it shows only times before 12am and later allocates time as 24hr format